# How to find xpath of Reactjs based application

Tags: reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am automating a web applications and unable to find the xpath of reactjs based application, I am getting three similar element for below reactjs:

```
<select placeholder="select" class="form-control" data-reactid=".0.0.1.0.0.1.$termsConditions-component.0.1.$=11.0.0.0.1.0.1"><option selected="" value="0" data-reactid=".0.0.1.0.0.1.$termsConditions-component.0.1.$=11.0.0.0.1.0.1.$0">

<select placeholder="select" class="form-control" data-reactid=".0.0.1.0.0.1.$termsConditions-component.0.1.$=11.0.0.0.1.0.1"><option selected="" value="0" data-reactid=".0.0.1.0.0.1.$termsConditions-component.0.1.$=11.0.0.0.1.0.1.$0">
```

Comment: provide full DOM image

Comment: what's the xpath you tried? have you tried using the index `[1]` and see if you are able to find the right element?